# Proper Method for such questions (Algebra)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I came across many questions which generally require manipulation of the terms. $(a,b,c \in \mathbb{R})$

For instance

$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=0$

In this case, we just multiply the equation with $2$ and obtain $a=b=c$ as a solution of the given equation. *I attribute this to pure intuition and observation.*

Another example

$a^2+b^2+5c^2+10d^2-6ad-4bc-6c-10d+34=0$

Now, again by observation we try to complete squares

$(a^2-6ad+9d^2)+(d^2-10d+25)+(4c^2-4bc+b^2)+(c^2-6c+9)=0$

$(a-3d)^2+(d-5)^2+(2c-b)^2+(c-3)^2$

Leading us to the solution

$a=15, b=6, c=3, d=5$

*My question is* Let's say I give the following equation

$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-ab-bc-cd-d+2/5=0$

( I can land on the solution by trying to make perfect squares.... but this is not an efficient method to solve )

***Is there any proper method to solve such equations ?***

*I'm not asking for a solution for this specific question rather a viable method which I could incorporate.*

*Thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the given equation to a quadratic equation with respect to a single variable, and you just need to satisfy the condition $\Delta_x≥0$ for the Polynomial Discriminant for the equation to have real roots. If the polynomial is homogeneous, you can divide all polynomial terms into a particular variable to reduce the number of variables and use the substitution, for example $ z = \dfrac{x}{y} $ (for a polynomial with variables $ x $ and $ y $). Sometimes various inequalities can be helpful. Think of it this way. It is not a good idea to use a general formula for a quartic equation where all roots are rational.  I will go over a simple example to show the "general way":

$$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac=0$$

$$\implies a^2-a(b+c)+(b^2+c^2-bc)=0$$

$$\implies \Delta_a =(b+c)^2-4(b^2+c^2-bc)=-3(b-c)^2≥0$$

$$\implies -3(b-c)^2=0\Longrightarrow b=c$$

$$\implies a=\dfrac {b+c}{2}=\dfrac {2b}{2}=b=c$$

So, we find real solutions as  $$a=b=c=\text {any real number}.$$

Comment: Thanks for this approach! Actually thought about it this but.. thought that would be too long, but I think this somewhat guarantees answer... Thanks again!